# Configurar Issabel con un SIP Trunk

Tags: asterisk

Tenemos un servicio contratado en 7Kas tenemos los datos del SIP configurados por autenticación IP, en su momento lo usábamos directamente con un programa en la pc que hacía las llamadas y listo.

Pero ahora me pidieron que configure un Issabel PBX para hacerlo un poco mas profesional y poner mas gente a utilizar las lineas desde diferentes lugares...

1_ como configuro Issabel con mi troncal SIP con autenticación por IP? (el SIP ya me dieron de alta en 7kas como autenticacion por ip y asignaron la del VPS que tenemos hosteado en OVH)

2_ desde el Issabel, como realizo llamadas? no encontré el dialer en ningun lado... o hay que conectar el programa que usabamos antes pero en lugar de poner los datos del SIP hay que poner los datos de Issabel?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Configurar un troncal SIP, seria:

1. Menú PBX y Configuración PBX

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Menú Básico > Troncales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Seleccionar: Añadir linea troncal SIP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Del formulario llenar como corresponda (Nombre del Troncal a nivel de Issabel, Identificador de Salida, etc). En "Opciones Salientes", definir el nombre que tendrá el troncal a nivel de Asterisk y los parámetros que el proveedor te proporcionado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez definido, guardas y aplicas los cambios.

Para las extensiones, deberás de generar extensiones en Issabel y configurar tus dispositivos (Softphones, Teléfonos físicos, etc) apuntando a Issabel.

Posterior es necesario generar reglas de salida, de las cuales debes definir que cuando coincida con el patrón de marcación (numero locales, móviles, internacionales), usar el troncal que creaste previamente.

Espero te sirva de guía. Saludos